# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class - rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

> I am completely unsure why i am getting this error - i believe i have
>   defined my variable correctly in my report controller - it does not
>   make sense to me why i am receiving the error. Any help in
>   understanding this would be much appreciated.

i currently get the error message

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

[image]

console

```
  Rendered reports/_form.html.erb (4.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_content_advert_show.html.erb (7.8ms)
  Rendered adverts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (10.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class:
  actionpack (4.1.10) lib/action_controller/model_naming.rb:9:in `model_name_from_record_or_class'
  actionview (4.1.10) lib/action_view/record_identifier.rb:47:in `dom_class'
  simple_form (3.0.2) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:58:in `simple_form_css_class'
  simple_form (3.0.2) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:19:in `simple_form_for'
  app/views/reports/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_reports__form_html_erb__795468471443709165_70250827830400'
  actionview (4.1.10) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.1.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
```

schema

```
  create_table "reports", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_report_id"
  end

  create_table "category_reports", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

report.rb

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category_report
  has_many :adverts
end
```

catergory_report.rb

```
class CategoryReport < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reports
  has_many :adverts
end
```

advert.rb

```
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
  belongs_to :category_report
end
```

reports / _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@report) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.association :category_report, collection: CategoryReport.all, prompt: "please choose", required: true, label: 'report this advert' %>
    <%= f.input :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "send report" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

reports_controller.rb

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_action :set_report, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @reports = Report.all
    respond_with(@reports)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@report)
  end

  def new
    @report = Report.new
    respond_with(@report)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @report = Report.new(report_params)
    @report.save
    respond_with(@report)
  end

  def update
    @report.update(report_params)
    respond_with(@report)
  end

  def destroy
    @report.destroy
    respond_with(@report)
  end

  private
    def set_report
      @report = Report.find(params[:id])
    end

    def report_params
      params.require(:report).permit(:content, :category_report_id)
    end
end
```

seed.rb

```
CategoryReport.delete_all
crt1 = CategoryReport.create!(name:'spam')
crt2 = CategoryReport.create!(name:'disturbing content')
crt3 = CategoryReport.create!(name:'incorrect information')
```

Comment: no one will probably be able to tell you unless you provide the params object from the controller and the route you're trying to hit. Is the show route possibly nested?

Comment: Based on your screenshot, you're requesting `/userrs/18/adverts/65` (is there a specific reason for the double 'r' in userrs?). I presume you're using the default Rails routes, so you're requesting the `show` action from `AdvertsController`, not `ReportsController`. Do you set `@report` in the `show` action from `AdvertsController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `before_action :set_report, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]` is in `ReportsController`. The controller causing the error is `AdvertsController`. You need to set the report in that controller, as well.

If you have this in many places, you may consider moving the method to the `ApplicationController`.

Instead of `@report` and a before filter, you may also consider something like:

```
helper_method: :report

def report
  @_report ||= params[:id] ? Report.find(params[:id]) : Report.new
end
```